# Is there a way I can compare the same variable and choose the higher one and print it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math, watch

The value of y is changing every time the while loops continues, I tried the watchpoints modules but I need a way  to find out the highest y has ever been and print it, I'll print the code that I'm trying to get to work.

```
import random
from watchpoints import watch

def alg(I):
    print(I)
    x = 1
    while i > 1:
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            i = int(i / 2)
            x = x + 1
        else:
            i = int(3 * i + 1)
            x = x + 1
        print(I)
        y = 1
        if i in range(1, 9):
            y = 1
        if i in range(10, 99):
            y = 2
        if i in range(100, 999):
            y = 3
    if i in range(1000, 9999):
        y = 4
    watch(a)#I want to know when y reachest the highest
    print(y, "is the max number of caracters")#then print it
    print("numero passaggi = ", str(x))


print("1: choice")
print("2: random")
type = int(input(" 1 or 2: "))
if type == 1:
    i = input("Enter a number: ")
    alg(int(I))
elif type == 2:
    i = random.randint(1, 100)  # 10^9
    alg(I)
else:
    print("Enter 1 or 2")
```

I want to know when `y` reaches the highest and print it below.

Comment: You can create a variable `max_y` and update the variable every time if the new `y` is greater than the `max_y` . You can keep a track from there.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but since you seem interested in "watching" the values of `y` as they change, one good option might be to make your `alg` function a generator that yields the values of `y`.  The caller can then do whatever it wants with those values, including taking the `max` of them.

Note that instead of doing this kind of thing to figure out how many digits a number has:

```
        if i in range(1, 9):
            y = 1
        if i in range(10, 99):
            y = 2
        if i in range(100, 999):
            y = 3
        if i in range(1000, 9999):
            y = 4
```

you can just do:

```
y = len(str(i))
```

i.e. turn it into a string and then count the characters.

```
def alg(i: int):
    x = 1
    while i > 1:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i = i // 2
            x += 1
        else:
            i = 3 * i + 1
            x = x + 1
        print(f"i: {i}")
        yield len(str(i))
    print(f"numero passaggi = {x}")

print(f"Max number of digits: {max(alg(50))}")
```

```
i: 25
i: 76
i: 38
i: 19
i: 58
i: 29
i: 88
i: 44
i: 22
i: 11
i: 34
i: 17
i: 52
i: 26
i: 13
i: 40
i: 20
i: 10
i: 5
i: 16
i: 8
i: 4
i: 2
i: 1
numero passaggi = 25
Max number of digits: 2
```

Comment: nice code and it works fine, but can I ask why in {max(alg(50))} you used 50, now the code always start with 50, what do I have to write to make it random or a choice? Thanks again

Comment: nevermind, found a way to make it work, thank you so much. This is my first project and was stuck with this problem for days...... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to create another variable to store the highest value that `y` has achieved and run a check each loop to see if the new `y` value is larger than the previous max.

Here is an example:

```
def exampleFunc():
    i = 0
    y = yMax = 0
    while i < 20:
        y = random.randint(1, 100)
        if y > yMax:
            yMax = y
        i += 1
    print(yMax)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to approach something like this is to transform your function into one that returns all intermediate values, and then aggregate those (in this case, using the builtin `max()`).

```py
from math import log10

def collatz_seq(n):
    yield n
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        else:
            n //= 2
        yield n

def print_stats(n):
    seq = collatz_seq(n)
    idx, val = max(enumerate(seq), key=lambda x: x[1])
    digits = int(log10(val)) + 1

    print(f"{digits} is the max number digits")
    print(f"{idx} is the iteration number")
```

Here I use `enumerate()` to give me the index of each value, and I use `math.log10()` to obtain the number of digits in the number (minus one).